# Scroll DayPicker to selected days months

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I am using DayPicker in overlay. I have set the selected from date as 17th August 2020 and I am setting DayPicker to show months from current to 12 months onward.

I want my DayPicker to scroll into selected date month (which is August in our case). But it is showing current month as default open.

I have tried multiple combination of props available, but nothing helps. 
I have created a codesandbox for the same.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-day-picker-examplesselected-dz5pv?file=/example.js

PS: I can do this by Javascript, but I want to know if there is any default props available for this.